# MySQL выбор синонимов иностранного слова

Tags: mysql, сортировка

Имеется база словаря (англо-малайский): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/716dc2/1

И в таблице словам "gun" и "riffle" соответствует одно слово "ആബേ" - то есть "пистолет" и "винтовка" - синонимы.

И мне нужно, чтобы в выборке, "gun" и "riffle" выводились один раз, через запятую:

---

അരറോൺ - foo

ആബേ     - gun, riffle

ചുരുക്കി - fool

etc.

---

Позиций должно выводиться, скажем, по 5, независимо, встречаются ли синонимы.

Спасибо.

Comment: GROUP BY + GROUP_CONCAT()

Comment: Спасибо, Akina! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/716dc2/7

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/716dc2/9